# Spring Boot + JPA+Thymeleaf+Hibernate multiple validation annotation applied

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, annotations

Before writing my problem, i have search a lot on internet. But i did not found any clue to overcome this issue.

My problem is multiple validation annotation applying of POJO field.

**for Exp:**

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp="(^[0-9]{10})")
private String mobileNumber;
```

If i do not enter any thing and left blank, then both the validation applied and both messages displayed. I just want one validation applied at a time and only one message display at a time.

I am using Spring boot and thymeleaf as template engine.

Comment: Well, both validation failires are fired, but you want do display only one of them -   go edit your timeleaf templates.

Comment: How, there is th:errors attribute which displays all errors associated with the field.

Comment: but this attribute is backed by thymeleaf template - which you can alter

Answer (score 1):

You have two way to solve this situation.

1. You may remove `@NotNull`. `@Pattern` annotation also does not accept null value and modify your error message.
2. [Create custom validation annotation](http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/) which combine two annotation in one.

Comment: how many custom validation will i create there could be more than one combinations. I need a ways by which i can stop next annotation not to apply if there is already fired.

Comment: Sorry for late response. You can create custom validation how many do you want.